Which iPhones can be found when powered off?
I have a question about lost and stolen iPhones.
My understanding is, should an iPhone get lost or stolen, the owner can use Find my iPhone to track the location and recover it.
Certain iPhones have the ability to be tracked, even when powered off, like when the battery has run out.
My question is, which iPhone models can be tracked when powered off using Find my iPhone?

iOS 15 introduced the Find My feature that works even when the device is turned off.  The applicable models  are: the iPhone 11 through iPhone 15.
Source: The Verge Guide to the iPhone 

Find My introduces new capabilities to help locate a device that has been turned off or erased, as well as live-streaming locations for family and friends who choose to share their location. Separation Alerts notify a user if they leave an AirTag, Apple device, or Find My network accessory behind in an unfamiliar location…

Source:  Apple iOS 15 Press Release

How does it do that even when the battery is dead? Passive RFID that is picked up by other iPhones with a known location? By the way, this is obviously a privacy nightmare. Is Siri listening as well when the phone is off?

@Allan do you have a source for that information? If you provide a link to something at least semi-reputable then I can mark your reply as accepted. Much appreciated.

There’s reserve for its location services @Peter-ReinstateMonica. Also keep in mind that a battery is not dead.  There’s still at least 6V of charge left.  It’s not enough to power the phone, but enough to power the GPS chip and WiFi
